# The specific CSS in assets/stylesheet cannot be read

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, assets

I would like to accomplish that
.html.erb file, which calls class in the form “class=”,  can read the all class defined in CSS files in app/assets/stylesheet, in development environment.

In app/assets/stylesheet, 30 .css files exist and all classes are defined in the files separately.

I think the problem exists in some configuration rather than the code mistake because changing filename of CSS in assets/stylesheet solves the problem.

In my case, "app/assets/stylesheet/admin/users.css" does not work, while "app/assets/stylesheet/admin/members.css" does. (any name except "users.css" is okey).

I attempted the following.

1. Super reloading the target page in some browsers (Chrome, Opera , FireFox).
2. Rebooting the OS .
3. Removing tmp/cache.
4. Removing “.DS_store” files in app/assets and app/assets/stylesheet.
5. Writing 
     "config.assets.debug = True"
   in the configure/environments/development.rb

I would like to get information about the question “Why just changing the filename of CSS in assets/stylesheet cause reading error.”

Comment: Can you provide some lines in your `layout` to embed stylesheet files? Also your `application.css` would be great.

Comment: `.search__box p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #767676;
}`

in app/assets/stylesheet/admin/users.css, and 

`//= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require selectize
 *= require selectize.default`

in app/assets/stylesheets/admin/application.css